# Override Framework Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding, prototype

I've seen tons of examples of how to override a jQuery core function such as:

```
jQuery.fn.remove = function(){};
```

I am attempting to override a method in the jqWidgets framework I'm using, it is built on top of jQuery. The method I am focused on is the *close* method of the *jqxWindow* object.

**Object Init:**

```
$("#myWindowDiv").jqxWindow({ settingsVar });
```

**Method Call:**

```
$("#myWindowDiv").jqxWindow('close');
```

**Framework Init:** (source code)

```
    var jqxBaseFramework = window.minQuery || window.jQuery;
    (function(a) {
        a.jqx = a.jqx || {};
        ...
        ...
        ...
    })(jqxBaseFramework);
```

**Window Object Init:** (source code)

```
    (function(a) {
       a.jqx.jqxWidget("jqxWindow", "", {});
       a.extend(a.jqx._jqxWindow.prototype, {
           defineInstance: function() {},
           ...
           ...
           ...
           close: function(){
               //FUNCTION I WANT TO OVERRIDE
           },
           ...
           ...
           ...
   })(jqxBaseFramework);
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Can this be easily achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like

```
jqxBaseFramework.jqx._jqxWindow.prototype.close = function() {};
```